# Storing variables from parsed text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

The text file contains information that I want to use with my website for logging in purposes

Text file contains the following..line by line

**user:password
user2:user2password**

I have tried using blob to read the text file but variables are not getting stored so I would like to know where I am going wrong or if I am even able to read the file using this method

```
function readFile(){
    var fileName = txtName.value;
    file = login.txt;
    var blob = file.read();
    var readText = blob.text;
    var lines = data.split("\n && : " );
        //Adding the file content to the label placed
    lblFileContent.setText(readText);
    Ti.API.info(readText);
    // dispose of file handle & blob.
    file = null;
    blob = null;
}
```

Comment: What’s `TI`? What’s `txtName`? What’s `login`? Are there any errors? Is `"\n && : "` a mistake? Is this in a browser?

Comment: I don't think you can read a textfile with javascript, try calling a php-script via an Ajax-request that does the reading

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past to read a txt-file:

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
function readFile() {
    $.post('path/to/php/read_file.php', {
        dir: 'path/to/file',
        file: 'file_name.txt',
    },function(file_contents) {
        if (file_contents != '') {
            //your code here
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    /* This script is invoked by 'index.html'.
     * This script gets the content of the file that has been changed by 
     * the admin, and uses it to determine the path of the file 
     * that is currently set by the admin.
     */
    $dir = $_POST["dir"];
    $file = $_POST["file"];
    $contents= '';

    if ($dhandle = opendir("$dir")) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($dhandle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                if ($entry == $file) {
                    $entry_path = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry;

                    $fhandle = fopen($entry_path, 'r');
                    $value = fread($fhandle, filesize($entry_path));
                    fclose($fhandle);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dhandle);

        echo "$contents";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try HTML 5 file API

1) To specify the text file add an input type file HTML tag (this will show a file selection dialog, if clicked).

```
<input type="file" id="myFileId">
```

2) Add a listener that will be executed when you choose a file, which triggers a 'change' event.

```
    document.getElementById('myFileId').addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    });
```

3) In the EventListener use FileReader to read your text file.

```
    document.getElementById('myFileId').addEventListener('change', function(e) {

        var file = document.getElementById('myFileId').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {

            var userPass = reader.result.split(" "); // split by space
            // userPass is an array where each element has a user:pass 
            // do your stuff


        } // onload

        reader.readAsText(file);

    });
```

You might want to check for file type/size before trying to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you may be interested in.

**Text file named login.txt containing** I'm reading this file using JavaScript.

```
user
myuser
password
myuserpassword
```

**My JavaScript code**

```
var loadXMLDoc=function(){
    var Credentials={};

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==0){
            var temp=xmlhttp.responseText.split('\n');

            for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                switch(temp[i].trim()){
                    case "user":
                    case "User":
                        Credentials.Username=temp[i+1];
                        break;
                    case "password":
                    case "Password":
                        Credentials.Password=temp[i+1];
                        break;
                }
            }

            console.log(Credentials); //Printing the object in the console.
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML `input`. Please note I'm call the js function here.

```
<input type="button" id="load" value="Click me!" onclick="loadXMLDoc();"/>
```

**Print the password in console with a `function getPassword("myuser")`.**

```
var getPassword=function(username){ // It takes one string parameter which is the username.
    var password="";
    if(Credentials.Username){
        if(Credentials.Username.trim()==username) password=Credentials.Password;
    }
    return password;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your example but would it possible to have the script save data inside variables so that when I type myuser in the console it will tell me value of that which is myuserpassword?

Comment: I dare to say but its not possible. Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: @user3689824 You can write a function to return the password of the user. I've updated my answer to match your requirement.